# How to avoid too many sessions stored?

Tags: perl, session, redis, session-timeout, catalyst

I'm using Perl Catalyst with `Catalyst::Plugin::Session::State::Cookie` and `Catalyst::Plugin::Session::Store::Redis`. I have at most 2,000 users logged in, but I have more than 2 millions keys in my Redis store.

Most of the authentications are done through an API key. I wonder if each API call gets a new session created and stored (there is likely no cookie in the API call), or if all new visitors to the web site gets a session created automatically.

It looks like a solution would be to set up a very short expiration by default (a few minutes), and override it with a longer expiration when users log in through the web interface.

I was wondering was is the best way to restrict the number of sessions stored to a minimum.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Redis Time out is meant for this purpose, Unless you have any specific pressing usecase to prevent all your sessions from expiring (I Can't see any) you should set it to practical time limit (default:300).

However this has problems in older version of redis so before testing this feature you need to get latest redis installed to fix it.